# How Install SSL Certificate on ha proxy dockerfile using letsencrypt

Tags: docker, ssl, haproxy

I am using haproxy to route the domains and subdomains and it is deployed on port 80. I want that all the domains should be https or using SSL certificate.

```
global
  log xx.xx.90.28 local0
  log xx.xx.90.28 local1 notice
  maxconn 2048

defaults
  log global
  mode http
  option httplog
  option dontlognull
  option redispatch
  option forwardfor
  option http-server-close
  retries 3
  timeout connect 5000
  timeout client 10000
  timeout server 10000

frontend balancer
  bind *:80
  mode http
  stats enable
  stats uri /stats
  stats refresh 15s
  stats show-node
  stats auth admin:admin
  acl domain hdr_dom(host) -i www.example.com
  acl subdomain hdr_dom(host) -i app.example.com
  acl subdomain1 hdr_dom(host) -i examplecom
  use_backend go_app_1 if domain
  use_backend go_app_2 if subdomain
  use_backend go_app_3 if subdomain1

backend go_app_1
  balance roundrobin
  mode http
  option forwardfor
  server go xx.xx.90.28:8081 check

backend go_app_2
  balance roundrobin
  mode http
  option forwardfor
  server go xx.xx.90.28:8082 check

backend go_app_3
  balance roundrobin
  mode http
  option forwardfor
  server go xx.xx.90.28:8081 check
```

And here is the DockerFile

```
FROM haproxy:2.1
COPY haproxy.cfg /usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
```

Now I want to use letsencrypt to secure these URL please guide me how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think we need to setup letsencrypt locally first.

And inject the result setting to the container via volume mount.

Example command from [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/haproxy):

`docker run -d --name my-running-haproxy -v /path/to/etc/haproxy:/usr/local/etc/haproxy:ro haproxy:1.7`

Something like below:

`-v /my/letsencrypt/setting/:/etc/ssl/`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
But it seems unclear to me how we can use letsencrypt with haproxy in Docker.